# create shortcut to network directory with different user

Tags: network-shares, shortcuts, runas

I am trying to use a shortcut to open a network directory as a different user but it's not working properly.

In the *Target* of my shortcut I have this:

```
C:\Windows\System32\runas.exe /DOMAINNAME\UserName explorer.exe "\\ServerName\drive$\directory"
```

what am I doing wrong - it just opens the My Documents folder

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The reason the command fails is that you need to quote the entire command with it's arguments, otherwise you're just passing more arguments to `runas`.

Consider:

```
C:\Windows\System32\runas.exe /user:DOMAINNAME\UserName "explorer.exe \"\\ServerName\drive$\directory\""
```

I think you need the `/user:` part there too, so I've included that for completion.

It could also default to `Documents` if it can't access the path for some reason.

Comment: That is interesting =) I didn't realize that was an option. Thanks I learn something new :) At least this way, it won't map a drive, but simply open it as a different user...

Comment: This will probably only work if you're using a windows-AD domain. With for example a Linux samba-server and system users, I doubt this would work.

Answer (score 1):

Use `Net Use` Command

What you want is:

> net use x: \\servername\drive$\directory * /user:username

Basically it creates a mapped network drive on x: (or any drive of your choice) that points to \servername\drive$\directory. * refers that it will prompt you for password. And /user:username refers to what username to use.

If you don't want it to prompt you for password, you can write your password in there.

I hope this helps.

Note: If you already connected to that share drive as a different user previously, it will fail. You will need to remove any current connection with other username.

Comment: how can I pass the password in the TARGET?

Comment: To put the password into the net use command? Put the password as part of the command `net use x: \\servername\drive$\directory /user:username password` separated with a space. Note: Not recommended to put as part of a batch script as the password is in the clear (anyone can read the password from the batch file).